# Error "/lib/modules/3.18.7-v7+/build No such file or directory" when compiling drivers for wifi dongle

Tags: raspbian, wifi, make

I'm trying to follow this instruction:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/porjo/mt7601.git
$ cd mt7601/src
$ make
$ mkdir -p /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/
$ cp RT2870STA.dat /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/
$ insmod os/linux/mt7601Usta.ko
```

from https://github.com/porjo/mt7601, to install drivers for my cheap usb wifi dongle (`lsusb` shows it is `148f:7601`), but when I call `make` I get error

```
/lib/modules/3.18.7-v7+/build No such file or directory.
```

How can I fix it? Maybe someone know another solution to make this dongle work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a complete kernel framework to build a kernel module.  Search for Raspberry PI compiling kernel modules and you should get the drift.

Every time you update the kernel you will have to re-compile the module.

I'm going to guess you have a Mediatek wireless dongle.

Luckily,  I think [MrEngman](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=760070#p760070) publishes an up to date kernel module.

Find your kernel with the following command

```
uname -a
```

Download the module using the following command

```
wget https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/80256631/mt7601-3.18.13-784.tar.gz
tar xzf mt7601-3.18.13-784.tar.gz
./install.sh
```

Using the values for 3.18.13-784 shown by uname -a.

Note that the Pi2 typically has -v7 as part of the kernel name, you'll need to take that into account.

e.g. on a Pi2 the download might be

```
wget https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/80256631/mt7601-3.18.13-v7-784.tar.gz
```

It's your job to check that what I suggest is safe and secure.

Comment: Joan beat me to it by 2 mins ... just to add: you might be much easier off if you just bought a new WiFi dongle with known support for raspberry Pi. I'm a big fan of the Edimax Un7811 dongle - sets you back less than $10 and it has full support in the rPi kernel.

Comment: @joan, thanks for this answer. I think im in a good way to solve it but I doesn't work yet. I think after run `install.sh` and reboot I should see `mt7601Usta` in result of `lsmod` but it is not there. Also `ra0` is not created. Any idea why? `uname -a` shows `3.18.13-785` so I've downloaded for tar for 785. Im also bit confused why `install.sh` puts the bin into `/lib/modules/3.18.13+` (not to `lib/modules/3.18.13-v7+`)

Comment: Ok, nevermind. `uname -a` shows `3.18.13-v7+` and If I forgot to add `-v7` to download url.

Comment: @akn That caught me out as well.  I'll edit that into the reply.

Comment: @PhilB. I paid less than $2 incl. shiping from aliexpress :) "No pain no gain"

Comment: Understood - but then you spent 6 manhours in trying to get it to work ... how much did that cost? :)

Comment: @joan Is there a guide on how to address what is in MrEngman's dropbox repository?  I was looking for `Linux raspberrypi 4.4.38+ #938 ...  armv6l GNU/Linux` but I've been unable to figure out the translation.  The link you provided didn't seem to help, or I'm just doing it wrong? `https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/80256631/mt7601-4.4.38-938.tar.gz` is a fail.